# Restrict scrapy from crawling subdomains

Tags: regex, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I have about 200 domains that I need to crawl, but I am certain no valuable informationed for me is contain in the subdomains, therefore I would like to exclude them from crawling.

For domain example.com I could use deny rule

```
(www.)*\w+\.example
```

but this approach would make me write 200 deny rules for every domain. My question is whether it is possible to create a deny rule for all subdomains of every domain?

Snippet from the spider:

```
class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "courses"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.eb-zuerich.ch',
]

    allowed_domains = ['eb-zuerich.ch',]


    rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),
                       deny=(r'.+[sS]itemap', r'.+[uU]eber', r'.+[kK]ontakt', r'.+[iI]mpressum',
                        r'.+[lL]ogin', r'.+[dD]ownload[s]?', r'.+[dD]isclaimer',
                        r'.+[nN]ews', r'.+[tT]erm', r'.+[aA]nmeldung.+',
                        r'.+[Aa][Gg][Bb]', r'/en/*', r'\.pdf$')),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True)
]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        # get soup of the current page
        soup = bs(response.body, 'html.parser')
        page_soup = bs(response.body, 'html.parser')

        # check if it is a course description page
        ex = Extractor(response.url, soup, page_soup)
        is_course = ex.is_course_page()
        if is_course:
            ex.save_course_info()
```

I am using Scrapy 1.4.0 and Python 3.6.1

Comment: What do you mean by "deny rule"? Where are you defining these rules? Can you share your spider code so far, and what works and what does not for your use case?

Comment: @paultrmbrth deny rule is a part of the spider crawling rule defined in the spider class. Please have a look at the code I added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether it is possible to create a deny rule for all subdomains of every domain?

With a simplistic approach (ignoring top-level domain names like `.co.uk`):

`r'^(https?)?//([^./]+\.){2,}[^./]+(/|$)'`